# How to create a test environment with IBM Bluemix Delivery Pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-deployment, devops, delivery-pipeline

Using the Delivery Pipeline service, I'd like to deploy my artifacts to staging/QA environments where QA/Product team members can test features/defect fixes before those changes get merged into Production branch.

How would I spin up these temporary testing environments when pull requests are created?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to build off of pull requests.  One option would be to have a separate branch that people can merge code into. You can then have a build stage which builds that branch and a deploy stage to deploy to your staging/qa environment.  You can then have another stage will does the merge into the production branch.  (Note, this stage should only be triggered manually.)